# Anaconda breaks command line Xcode builds

Tags: xcode, build, environment-variables, anaconda, ld

When Anaconda is installed on a Mac, it sets environment variable `LD=/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-ld`.

When running an Xcode build from command line (like building a Carthage dependency), the value of `LD` gets inserted into the linker command:

```
Ld /Users/maxim/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/DerivedData/10.1_10B61/GeoJSONMap/0.0.8/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/GeoJSONMap/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/GeoJSONMap.framework/GeoJSONMap normal arm64 (in target: GeoJSONMap)
    cd /Users/maxim/Carthage/Checkouts/GeoJSONMap
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=11.0
    /anaconda3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-ld -arch arm64 -dynamiclib <... skipped for brevity ...>
```

...which results in `ld: unknown option: -dynamiclib`.

So, the question is: how to avoid this interference in a proper way? Is it possible to get the variable `LD` out of Xcode build process? Is it possible to configure Anaconda to use some other variable instead? Is there a way to unset Anaconda setting temporarily when running Xcode builds? What is the intended value of `LD` that Xcode expects?

Comment: Running `conda deactivate` enough times should remove any conda-specific things from your environment (with the exception of the conda shell function itself)

Comment: @darthbith thanks a lot, it should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With conda versions greater than or equal to 4.5 (I think), it should be sufficient to run

```
conda deactivate
```

to remove conda-specific environment variable settings from your shell. You may need to run `conda deactivate` several times if you have environments other than the `base` one activated.